# RxJava - ConnectableObservable can't notify its observers more than 128 times when using observeOn and subscribeOn simultaneously

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an application that uses a ConnectableObservable that runs for a long time. Mysteriously after some time its observer stopped getting notifications in its onNext() method.

I have written the following test that simplifies the example. It's just a ConnectableObservable with an infinite loop, with one subscriber using both observeOn and subscribeon. After 128 `s.onNext(1)` calls it stops notifying the observer.

```
@Test
public void testHotObservable() throws InterruptedException{

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ConnectableObservable<Integer> observable = Observable.<Integer>create( (s) -> {
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            s.onNext(1);
        }
    })
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .publish();

    Observer<Integer> observer = new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer i) {
            System.out.println("got "+i);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    observable.subscribe(observer);
    observable.connect();

    latch.await();
}
```

This is what I've seen debugging RxJava's code I have found out the reason why it doesn't call the Observer's onNext() method but I don't understand it:

1.- `s.onNext(1);` is called:

2.- The execution gets to `rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue()`:

```
void pollQueue() {
    int emitted = 0;
    final AtomicLong localRequested = this.requested;
    final AtomicLong localCounter = this.counter;
    do {
        localCounter.set(1);
        long produced = 0;
        long r = localRequested.get();            
        for (;;) {
            ...
            System.out.println("R: "+r);
            if (r > 0) {
                Object o = queue.poll();
                if (o != null) {
                    child.onNext(on.getValue(o));
                    r--;
```

**The problem is the value of r**. The first time it executes its value is always 128. After each call it decrements by 1 (`r--`). This means that **ConnectableObservable can only notify its observers 128 times when using both observeOn and subscribeOn**. If I remove subscribeOn, r's value starts over each iteration and it works.

**UPDATE**:

I found a solution: the problem was caused by the order of the `.observerOn().subscribeOn()`. If I reverse it to `.subscribeOn().observeOn()` it works (I can see that the value of `r` is always reset to 128).

Anyway I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Are `state` and `signal` volatile variables?

Comment: Nope...is it neccesary?

Comment: Yes, otherwise changes across threads may not be visible or the variable read may be hoisted out of the loop entirely.

Comment: Added volatile but it still stops after some time...I'm wondering if it could  be because of the `signal = null; ` statement right after the `s.onNext(signal);`... I doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Maybe your signal source stops, not the observable.

Comment: Just checked it but it still sets the signal. I'm updating the question with what I've found out debugging

Comment: Did you subscribe to the observable? It seems nothing consumes your signal and the internal buffer just fills in.

Comment: @akarnokd See the update in the question, I fixed it but still don't understand why it happens. I'd appreciate an explanation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many async operators use internal, fixed size buffers and rely on subscribers requesting requently. In your case, something doesn't request properly which I can't say what it is. I suggest trying your use case with standard components to see what could be wrong, i.e., you can replace your custom Observable with a PublishSubject + sample:

```
Subject<Integer, Integer> source = PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

ConnectableObservable<Integer> co = source.sample(
    500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
.onBackpressureBuffer().publish();

co.subscribe(yourSubscriber);
co.connect();

source.onNext(1);
```